# Create a dtm using tokens

Tags: r

I try to run tis command

```
dtm <- CreateDtm(tokens$text, 
                 doc_names = tokens$ID, 
                  ngram_window = c(1, 2))
```

However I receive this error:

```
Error in seq.default(1, length(tokens), 5000) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In CreateDtm(tokens$text, doc_names = tokens$ID, ngram_window = c(1,  :
  No document names detected. Assigning 1:length(doc_vec) as names.
```

Any idea what I have to change in order to run it properly?

Comment: Please edit your question to make it a minimally reproducible example so that those that answer know they have resolved the issue. So which library is being used - textmineR I think - so 'library(textmineR)' is important to include. Then for the data, include the output of `dput(tokens)` in the question ensuring that the data included shows the problem.

Comment: @AndrewChisholm yes textmineR is the library and I included it in the code I run. The dataset is very large. Is there an alternative to provide a small option of dput()?

Comment: @ErikBodg is tokens$text a character vector?

Comment: @ErikBodg Please edit the original question with the exact code that shows the problem. Do this by reducing the data down so it can easily be placed into the question. If reducing in this way makes the problem go away then you've learnt something that might help. You can probably try `tokens$text[1:10]` and `tokens$ID[1:10]` as candidate small data sets.